# Why is this showing partially solved at codeeval.com

Tags: java

what's the problem in this:

```
static int hex(String s){
    String[] dd = s.split("");
    int d = 0;
    int r = dd.length;

    for(int b=0; b<r; b++){
        dd[b] = dd[b].replace("a","10");
        dd[b] = dd[b].replace("b","11");
        dd[b] = dd[b].replace("c","12");
        dd[b] = dd[b].replace("d","13");
        dd[b] = dd[b].replace("e","14");
        dd[b] = dd[b].replace("f","15");
        dd[b] = dd[b].replace("g","16");
    }

    for(int b=1; b<r; b++){
        d += Integer.parseInt(dd[b]) * Math.pow(16,r-b-1);
    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Well ... You should explain us what the _problem_ is, we can help with the solution. At least, tell us the requirement as well as the expected and the actual output. Additionally, this kind of problems can usually be solved by debugging your program, often with pen and paper.

Comment: `dd[b]=dd[b].replace("g","16");` is redundant.

Comment: It's simply incorrect. [It converts `ff` to 15](http://ideone.com/VF48n9). (And it'd convert anything with a single hex character to `0`).

Comment: It's giving correct output in aide but not at code eval

Comment: Bathsheba if it is renudant then what's the alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked after replacing  (int b=1) by(int b=2) in the loop
Because when splitting a character with "" it creates a empty character in the array at index 0 in aide and other ide but not at codeval and https://www.compilejava.net that's why it was ignoring the first character and giving 13 for value ed